# Powering externally a 3v a 2 relay module

Tags: power-supply, esp8266

I'm using an ESP8266 to control a [dual relay module](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32847869020.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.4db347bagZ4kUT&algo_pvid=null&algo_expid=null&btsid=0b0a187b16100403766566833e03a2&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_). As a good practice, and a longer life for the MCU, I wish to power it not using its `vcc` and `gnd` pins, but using its `JDVcc`.

Appreciate explanation whether a 5v input into `JDVcc` is valid and won't damage the module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using 5V as a supply to power a relay coils that are rated for 3V is not valid and it might damage the module.

Comment: A 3v coil is not suited for a 5v input. I know. But JDVcc transfers it directly as 5v?

Comment: Yes, JDVCC is directly the coil supply, so 5V is not suitable.